# change font size of posts in blogger

Tags: html, css, fonts, blogger

I'm trying to change the font size in my posts on blogger http://www.aspensummit.co and I'm not having any luck finding the body/post font size in the html section to change it.  I was able to change my header menu links and sidebar title sizes with no problem, but the actual blog posts are giving me trouble.  Is there a css override I can put in the customized template settings to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body post is inheriting font styles from this css rule in your file `summer-to-do-list.html`.

```
.post-body, .post-footer, .home-link, .older-link, .newer-link {
    font:400 11.5px'Raleway', sans-serif;
    line-height:1.6;
}
```

If you can change this rule, then setting any `font-size` by replacing `11.5px` from `font:400 11.5px'Raleway', sans-serif;` will change the font-size.

But, if you cannot change that rule, then adding a more specific rule will override this style, such as:

```
body .post-body, .post-footer, .home-link, .older-link, .newer-link {
    font:400 14px'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

You can also try `!important` but that's not advisable:

```
.post-body{
    font:400 14px'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    line-height:1.6;
}
```

Or maybe a more specific css selector containing `ID` such as:

```
div[id^='post-body-']{
    font-size:16px;//Or any value.
}
```

Here `[id^='post-body-']` is a css selector for all the elements having id starting with `post-body-` .